# TypeError: get_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'origin'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use my own .txt file in tensorflow, but when I run it in jupyter notebook i get this

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-b7f323158fac> in <module>
      5 import time
      6 
----> 7 path_to_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('https://storage.googleapis.com/jezuz/Jezuz.txt?x-goog-signature=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&x-goog-algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&x-goog-credential=jezuz-819%40cybernetic-day-275502.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20200621%2Fus%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&x-goog-date=20200621T190757Z&x-goog-expires=600&x-goog-signedheaders=host')
      8 with open('Jezuz.txt') as file_object:
      9         contents = file_object.read()

TypeError: get_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'origin'
```

this is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
import os
import time

path_to_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('https://storage.googleapis.com/jezuz/Jezuz.txt?x-goog-signature=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&x-goog-algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&x-goog-credential=jezuz-819%40cybernetic-day-275502.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20200621%2Fus%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&x-goog-date=20200621T190757Z&x-goog-expires=600&x-goog-signedheaders=host')
with open('Jezuz.txt') as file_object: 
    contents = file_object.read() 
    print(contents)
```

Comment: I don't understand where you're confused: the `getfile` documentation and error message are quite clear.  `getfile` requires two arguments, and you supplied only one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want here is:

```py
path_to_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Jezuz.txt', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/jezuz/Jezuz.txt?x-goog-signature=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&x-goog-algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&x-goog-credential=jezuz-819%40cybernetic-day-275502.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20200621%2Fus%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&x-goog-date=20200621T190757Z&x-goog-expires=600&x-goog-signedheaders=host')
```

Comment: FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-5f29ce8899c1> in <module>
      6 
      7 path_to_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Jezuz.txt', 'link')
----> 8 with open('Jezuz.txt') as file_object:
      9         contents = file_object.read()
     10         print(contents)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Jezuz.txt'

Comment: That's because `get_file()` is now throwing an exception because the server is coming back with a Bad Request (400) error.  So the URL you provided isn't right.  It looks like removing all the parameters works, but it's a completely unrelated problem to the one you reported.

Comment: the signed urls are too complicated and messy. im now using a direct link to my bucket
https://storage.googleapis.com/jezuz/Jezuz.txt

Answer (score 0):

I think this should fix your issue:

```
path_to_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Jezuz.txt', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/jezuz/Jezuz.txt')
with open(path_to_file, encoding="utf-8") as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read() 
    print(contents)
#This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with
#almost no restrictions whatsoever.  You may copy it, give it away or
#re-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included
```

Comment: i guess we've made progress? i got this error now
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 36276: character maps to <undefined>

im sorry if im not being very helpfull. im only 14

i thought i had encoded my text correctly

Comment: along with this
d:\new folder (9)\envs\tf-gpu\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

Comment: First of all, it's totally OK. Second of all, I'm twice your age, my friend **(feeling old)**. Third of all, are you using `python2` or `python3`? Because I'm using `python3` and it works just fine

Comment: @Anwarvic you should specify an encoding in your open call, otherwise it defaults to using your preferred locale (the one set by your environment--cp1252).  In this case, the file is UTF-8, so you should pass `encoding="utf-8"` to `open()` as well: `open(path_to_file, encoding="utf-8")`.  Note: these other issues are unrelated to your original question (which was how to make `get_file()` work).  SO questions are meant to solve one problem only.  While it's okay to ask for help, some are better asked as new questions.  And you should be willing to do some of your own research too. :-)

Comment: Thanks @JohnSzakmeister... I think this could be it

Comment: im using python 3 and i have specified encoding in my code ive always had the specification but it dosent help

Comment: okay so i used this
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
import os
import time

path_to_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Jezuz.txt', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/jezuz/Jezuz.txt')
with open(path_to_file, encoding="utf-8") as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read() 
    print(contents)

and got a whole mess of gibberish printed out
looks like the html code

Comment: @WildBoys54 Smells like something else is going on then.  I get text--no html.  Either way, I think both these answers answer your original question.  I suggest digging into the current issue a bit and then posting a new question, if you haven't been able to resolve it.  But the current issue should not be tied to the current question--it's unrelated.  Thanks!